# Date substracting

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapp-development, dapps

I've ran into weird problem. Let's assume we have a contract where in constructor:

```
startDate = now;
```

Later on after deployment, when I call the variable to do some math, for example:

```
newDate = startDate - now;
```

It returns completely bias result.
Did anyone had similar problem or now how to fix that?

Cheers!

Comment: Btw. is it okay to do math on uints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're subtracting a bigger number from a smaller number. If `newDate` is a `uint` it will overflow, producing a strangely large result.

If you want a positive number, subtract `startDate` from `now` not the other way around.

Comment: Crap, I'm just stupid it seems. :)
Btw. Is there any problem if I would use int256 instead of uint?